# Accounts and Wallets

Tags: wallets, accounts

Testing the GethJS console commands. I put in practice the *personal.listWallets* and *personal.listAccounts*. The first return me this value:

[image]

And the second command return me this:

[image]

It seems that are same things and I getting confuse

Comment: What are you confused about?

Comment: The confuse that I have is that I look bouth things same .But if bouth thing have different names will be because are differen things

Comment: Both aren't the same thing! It's more like, when you want to view only addresses of all the accounts in the wallet then you run the second command. But when you want all the details of all the addresses in the wallet, you run the first command.

Comment: So basiclly an account and a wallet are same thing. The diferrence is the command. personal.listAccounts return only the list of created address and the otrer command return same information but expading the info for each account no?

Comment: Wallets contain multiple accounts which have metadata like address, URL, status, etc. A wallet can contain multiple accounts. So consider there are 1000 accounts and you want a list of addresses associated with those 1000 accounts. In this case you can easily get the list using the second command, where as it would be quite hectic for you if you use the first command. The only **difference between the two** is that the second command is **filtered** with the condition of *displaying only addresses* of all the accounts in the wallet. Hope you understood!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **first** command lists all the **wallet details** which includes *accounts, status and URL* while the **second** command lists all the accounts i.e. the **account addresses.**